# Why does the React hook useRef throw an error when used?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

**The error**

This is the error that shows in the brower over the webpage.

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR


src\components\SignIn.js
  Line 5:21:  React Hook "useRef" is called in function "signin" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

**SignIn.js**

The part of my code that uses the React hook useRef.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { Card, Button, Form } from 'react-bootstrap'

export default function signin() {
    const userRef = useRef()

    return (
        <>
            <Card>
                <Card.Body>
                    <h2 className='text-center mb-4'>Magnet</h2>
                    <Form>
                        <Form.Group id="username">
                            <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type='text' ref={userRef} required />
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Form>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Your answer looks to be in the error message you posted. Please read through it thoroughly.

Comment: @BrianThompson Yes thanks for the help I see what I need to do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call a hook in a normal function, it must be called from a hook or functional component.

```
export default function signin()
```

The naming convention above doesn't refer to either. Change to `Signin`.
And indeed, the error message explains that.

Comment: @hectorwithc you should accept one of the answers which helped, that is common practice here.

Comment: Since you explained it well and where first with a answer I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You already have answer in your error

```
Line 5:21:  React Hook "useRef" is called in function "signin" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

you should change component name with `Signin`